# How to restart or shutdown a remote computer with comment from powershell

Tags: powershell

I have been looking for a way to restart/shutdown a remote computer with comment from powershell.

The traditional `Restart-Computer` Cmdlet does not have these options. then somewhere they advised to use the native command for `shutdown.exe`. But this command does not support the use of credentials like powershell does.

Comment: The documentation for `Restart-Computer` indicates that it uses the WMI `Win32Shutdown` method. You may be able to build upon the similar [`Win32ShutdownTracker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394057(v=vs.85).aspx) method that does incluse comment and reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a related research, I stumbled upon the WMI Class `Win32_OperatingSystem` which comes with a method `Win32ShutdownTracker`.

The documentation for the `Win32Shutdowntracker()` method is available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394057(v=vs.85).aspx

It takes four parameters as explained below:

- Timeout [Integer] in seconds
- Comment [String]
- Reason Code [Integer] Can be found here:
  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376885(v=vs.85).aspx)
- Flag [Integer] which will actually perform the function. (Explained
  in the documentation for win32Shutdowntracker)

So the code to Force Restart a remote machine becomes:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer).Win32Shutdowntracker(0, "This is a custom comment", 0x00000000, 6)
```

Adding Credentials through a `PScredential` object is now easy:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $CustomCredentials).Win32Shutdowntracker(0, "This is a custom comment", 0x00000000, 6)
```

Comment: https://powershellchronicles.com/2017/09/09/powershell-rebootshutdown-remote-machine-with-comment-2/